# How is Shaktimaan related to the Pandavas?

Tags: shaktimaan

It is stated in Wikipedia page of *[Shaktimaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktimaan)* that he was related to Bhishma as he was the descendant of Bhishma? Bhishma was the granduncle of the Pandavas according to **Mahabharata**. Also, he remained a bachelor for his entire life so how was he having descendants? Was Shaktimaan then related to the Pandavas who were related to Bhishma?

Comment: How can he have descendants? Bheeshma wasn’t the only child, his brother’s’ descendants were the pandavas and kauravas. So, quoting Obi Wan Kenobi- “they were right, ***from a certain point of view***”

Comment: Shaktimaan could have been related to the Mahabharata characters, I cannot be sure of that. But, everything isn’t always true on Wikipedia; just saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what statement from Wikipedia confused you. A simple find on [Shaktimaan page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktimaan) of Wikipedia revealed this:

> Bhishma Pitamah(Ganga putra) from the era of great Mahabharata is recognised as the ancestors of Shaktimaan and division of Shaktipunja into two pieces namely Shakti Punja (remained with Truth/Light) and Pap Punja (taken away by Andhera/Darkness).

This statement is factually (and grammatically) fully incorrect.

**During Mahabharata period, Shaktimaan existed as Satya who was by no means related with Pandavas.** From the same Wikipedia page:

> Later, it is revealed that Shaktimaan was the rebirth of Shri Satya who had formed the Suryanshi Sect after the war of the Mahabharat 5,000 years ago.

Again, this isn't fully correct as Suryanshi sect wasn't formed by Satya, but the part which says that Shaktimaan is re-incarnation of Satya is correct.

As to why some fans have written that Bhishma was ancestor of Shaktimaan is possibly because Mukesh Khanna (the actor and co-producer of Shaktimaan) had played the character Bhishma in the first Mahabharata TV series (which made TV famous in India). The production house in which Shaktimaan was produced is also named Bheeshma International.

**Update:**
Episode 77 (Shaktimaan learned that he is reincarnation of Satya):

(The episode also shows birth of Tamraj Kilvish and division of Shakti Punjya)

Comment: I've now edited the Wikipedia page to remove the incorrect information. Please, check the history of the page to verify quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I have been unable to find any reference to an episode stating that Shaktimaan is descended from Bhishma, so it is possible that the detail was edited into the Wikipedia by an over-zealous fan, possibly because the actor who portrays Shaktimaan, [Mukesh Khanna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukesh_Khanna), was previously famous for playing Bhisma Pitamah in B. R. Chopra's *Mahabharat*.

Comment: Also the production company of Shaktimaan is Bhishma  Production

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember the Mahabharata but according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhishma#In_The_Kurukshetra_War) Bhisma is the grand-uncle, not grandfather, of the Pandavas. Their grandfathers would have been Vyasa (paternal) and Shurasena (maternal).

I've never seen Shaktimaan.